# Table messing up formatting of text

Tags: html, css, anki

I am using Anki (you don't have to be familiar with this) which is a flashcard app. When designing the cards, I cannot figure out what is going wrong.

The **front** of the card:

```
<div class="front">
    {{#Title}}<div class="title">{{Title}}</div>{{/Title}}
    <div class="subtitle">Details</div>
    <table id="clozed">
      <tr>
        <td class="heading">Origin</td>
        <td>{{cloze:Text1}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="heading">Insertion</td>
        <td>{{cloze:Text2}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="heading">Innervation</td>
        <td>{{cloze:Text3}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="heading">Action</td>
        <td>{{cloze:Text4}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<script>
// Scroll to cloze
function scrollToCloze () {
    const cloze1 = document.getElementsByClassName("cloze")[0];
    const rect = cloze1.getBoundingClientRect();
    const absTop = rect.top + window.pageYOffset;
    const absBot = rect.bottom + window.pageYOffset;
    if (absBot >= window.innerHeight) {
        const height = rect.top - rect.bottom
        const middle = absTop - (window.innerHeight/2) - (height/2);
        window.scrollTo(0, middle);
    };
}
if ( document.readyState === 'complete' ) {
    setTimeout(scrollToCloze, 1);
} else {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        setTimeout(scrollToCloze, 1);
    }, false);
}
</script>
```

The **back** of the card:

```
<div class="back">
    {{#Title}}<div class="title">{{Title}}</div>{{/Title}}
    <div class="subtitle">Details</div>
    <table id="clozed">
      <tr>
        <td class="heading">Origin</td>
        <td>{{cloze:Text1}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="heading">Insertion</td>
        <td>{{cloze:Text2}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="heading">Innervation</td>
        <td>{{cloze:Text3}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="heading">Action</td>
        <td>{{cloze:Text4}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<script>
// Remove cloze syntax from revealed hint
var hint = document.getElementById("original");
if (hint) {
    var html = hint.innerHTML.replace(/\[\[oc(\d+)::(.*?)(::(.*?))?\]\]/mg,
                                      "<span class='cloze'>$2</span>");
    hint.innerHTML = html
};

// Scroll to cloze
function scrollToCloze () {
    const cloze1 = document.getElementsByClassName("cloze")[0];
    const rect = cloze1.getBoundingClientRect();
    const absTop = rect.top + window.pageYOffset;
    const absBot = rect.bottom + window.pageYOffset;
    if (absBot >= window.innerHeight) {
        const height = rect.top - rect.bottom
        const middle = absTop - (window.innerHeight/2) - (height/2);
        window.scrollTo(0, middle);
    };
}
if ( document.readyState === 'complete' ) {
    setTimeout(scrollToCloze, 1);
} else {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        setTimeout(scrollToCloze, 1);
    }, false);
}


// Reveal full list
var olToggle = function() {
    var orig = document.getElementById('original');
    var clozed = document.getElementById('clozed');
    var origHtml = orig.innerHTML
    orig.innerHTML = clozed.innerHTML
    clozed.innerHTML = origHtml
}
</script>
```

The **css styling** of the card:

```
html {
  /* scrollbar always visible in order to prevent shift when revealing answer*/
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.card {
  border: 1px solid #404040;
  padding: 8px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: left;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}

/* general layout */

.text {
  /* center left-aligned text on card */
  column-count: 2;
  display: inline-block;
  align: center;
  text-align: left;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 40em;
}

.hidden {
  /* guarantees a consistent width across front and back */
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
  line-height:0;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.title {
  background-color: #edcac5;
  color: #000000;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.subtitle {
  background-color: #3b3b3d;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.heading {
  color: #6395ff;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left;
  width: 30%;
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

/* clozes */

.cloze {
  /* regular cloze deletion */
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.card21 #btn-reveal{
  /* no need to display reveal btn on last card */
  display:none;
}

/* additional fields */

.extra{
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 40em;
}

.extra-entry{
  margin-top: 0.8em;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  text-align:left;
}

.extra-descr{
  margin-bottom: 0.2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1em;
}

#btn-reveal {
  font-size: 0.5em;
  display:none;
}

.mobile #btn-reveal {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  display:none;
}
```

This is how it is supposed to look:
[image]

But this is how it ends up looking:
[image]

I think the table has something to do with this, I greatly appreciate any help/feedback.

Comment: The table in `front` and the table in `back` share the same `id`. Id's must be unique. That may not be causing your problem, but I would fix that to eliminate it as a suspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went ahead and threw a `section id` and called it `wrapper` and give it a with. This way will minimize any format issues.

```js
// Scroll to cloze
function scrollToCloze () {
    const cloze1 = document.getElementsByClassName("cloze")[0];
    const rect = cloze1.getBoundingClientRect();
    const absTop = rect.top + window.pageYOffset;
    const absBot = rect.bottom + window.pageYOffset;
    if (absBot >= window.innerHeight) {
        const height = rect.top - rect.bottom
        const middle = absTop - (window.innerHeight/2) - (height/2);
        window.scrollTo(0, middle);
    };
}
if ( document.readyState === 'complete' ) {
    setTimeout(scrollToCloze, 1);
} else {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        setTimeout(scrollToCloze, 1);
    }, false);
}

// back of card

// Remove cloze syntax from revealed hint
var hint = document.getElementById("original");
if (hint) {
    var html = hint.innerHTML.replace(/\[\[oc(\d+)::(.*?)(::(.*?))?\]\]/mg,
                                      "<span class='cloze'>$2</span>");
    hint.innerHTML = html
};

// Scroll to cloze
function scrollToCloze () {
    const cloze1 = document.getElementsByClassName("cloze")[0];
    const rect = cloze1.getBoundingClientRect();
    const absTop = rect.top + window.pageYOffset;
    const absBot = rect.bottom + window.pageYOffset;
    if (absBot >= window.innerHeight) {
        const height = rect.top - rect.bottom
        const middle = absTop - (window.innerHeight/2) - (height/2);
        window.scrollTo(0, middle);
    };
}
if ( document.readyState === 'complete' ) {
    setTimeout(scrollToCloze, 1);
} else {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        setTimeout(scrollToCloze, 1);
    }, false);
}


// Reveal full list
var olToggle = function() {
    var orig = document.getElementById('original');
    var clozed = document.getElementById('clozed');
    var origHtml = orig.innerHTML
    orig.innerHTML = clozed.innerHTML
    clozed.innerHTML = origHtml
}
```

```css
html {
  /* scrollbar always visible in order to prevent shift when revealing answer*/
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.card {
  border: 1px solid #404040;
  padding: 8px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: left;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}

/* general layout */

.text {
  /* center left-aligned text on card */
  column-count: 2;
  display: inline-block;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: left;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 40em;
}

.hidden {
  /* guarantees a consistent width across front and back */
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
  line-height:0;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.title {
  background-color: #edcac5;
  color: #000000;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.subtitle {
  background-color: #3b3b3d;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.heading {
  color: #6395ff;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left;
  width: 30%;
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

/* clozes */

.cloze {
  /* regular cloze deletion */
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.card21 #btn-reveal{
  /* no need to display reveal btn on last card */
  display:none;
}

/* additional fields */

.extra{
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 40em;
}

.extra-entry{
  margin-top: 0.8em;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  text-align:left;
}

.extra-descr{
  margin-bottom: 0.2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1em;
}

#btn-reveal {
  font-size: 0.5em;
  display:none;
}

.mobile #btn-reveal {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  display:none;
}

/* new css */
#wrapper {
  width: 309px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<section id="wrapper">
<div class="front">
    <div class="title">Title</div>
    <div class="subtitle">Details</div>
    <table id="clozed">
      <tr>
        <td class="heading">Origin</td>
        <td>cloze:Text1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="heading">Insertion</td>
        <td>cloze:Text2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="heading">Innervation</td>
        <td>cloze:Text3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="heading">Action</td>
        <td>cloze:Text4</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<!-- back of card -->
<div class="back">
    <div class="title">Title</div>
    <div class="subtitle">Details</div>
    <table id="clozed">
      <tr>
        <td class="heading">Origin</td>
        <td>cloze:Text1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="heading">Insertion</td>
        <td>cloze:Text2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="heading">Innervation</td>
        <td>cloze:Text3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="heading">Action</td>
        <td>cloze:Text4</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</section>
```